# Ошибка TypeError: Wm.wm_withdraw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' при вызове Toplevel.withdraw()

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть код который делает установку приложение на Tkinter ( запустить сможете если замените все картинки )
Есть главное окно с выбором установки и языка (родительское), при выборе другого языка (открывается точно такое же окно с английским шрифтом). Там есть выбор установки при нажатие должно открыться новое окно, а дочернее окно с английским шрифтов уйти, что работает на русском, но на английском нужен параметр self, как его и куда внедрить. Образец кода :

```
def onlin2():                                                       
    onlin2 = Toplevel(tk)                                           
    onlin2.geometry("1290x900")                                     
    onlin2.title("online installer")                                
    onlin2.resizable(width=False, height=False)                     
    Toplevel.withdraw() 

def sozt():
    sozd = Toplevel(tk)                                            
    sozd.geometry("400x400")                                       
    sozd.title("О создателе")                                                                    
    sozd.resizable(width=False, height=False)                      

def oprog():
    oprog = Toplevel(tk)                                           
    oprog.geometry("800x400")                                      
    oprog.title("О программе")                                                                   
    oprog.resizable(width=False, height=False)                     
                                                    
    
def ext1():
    tk.destroy()                                                    

def ussb():                                                         
    usb = Toplevel(tk)                                              
    usb.geometry("1290x900")                                        
    usb.title("USB version")                                                                      
    usb.resizable(width=False, height=False)                        
    tk.withdraw()
                  

def change_language():                                              
    en = Toplevel(tk)                                               
    en.geometry("1290x900")                                         
    en.title("English version")                                     
    en.resizable(width=False, height=False)                         
    en.image = PhotoImage(file="image/ingl.png")                    
    screen2 = Label(en, image=en.image)                             
    screen2.grid(row=0, column=0)                                   
    bl = Button(en,image = online, command = onlin2)                
    bl.place(x=450,y=500, width=200, height=100)                    
    tk.withdraw()                                                   
  
def onlin():                                                        
    online= Toplevel(tk)                                           
    online.geometry("1290x900")                                     
    online.title("online installer")                                
    online.resizable(width=False, height=False)                     
    tk.withdraw()                                                   


from tkinter import *                                               

                                                                    

tk = Tk()                                                                                                                      
tk.title("D0LSTEK INSTALLER HELPER")                                
tk.geometry("1280x900")                                             
tk.image = PhotoImage(file="image/режим _установки.png")            
screen1 = Label(tk, image=tk.image)                                 
screen1.grid(row=0, column=0)                                       
tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)                             
sozd = PhotoImage(file="image/sozd.png")                              
bl = Button(tk,image = sozd, command = sozt)                        
bl.place(x=210,y=840, width=200, height=50)                         
OPROG = PhotoImage(file="image/o_programe.png")                       
bl = Button(tk,image = OPROG, command = oprog)                      
bl.place(x=210,y=790, width=200, height=50)                         
svapLANG = PhotoImage(file="image/key_english.png")                     
bl = Button(tk,image = svapLANG, command = change_language)         
bl.place(x=410,y=790, width=200, height=100)                        
online = PhotoImage(file="image/online.png")                                      
bl = Button(tk,image = online, command = onlin)                          
bl.place(x=450,y=500, width=200, height=100)                        
usb = PhotoImage(file="image/usb.png")                                              
bl = Button(tk,image = usb, command = ussb)                         
bl.place(x=650,y=500, width=200, height=100)                        
exit1 = PhotoImage(file="image/exit.png")                               
bl = Button(tk,image = exit1, command = ext1)                       
bl.place(x=10,y=790, width=200, height=100)                         
Button.pack                                                         

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: `а дочернее окно с английским шрифтов уйти, что работает на русском, но на английском нужен параметр self` - с чего вы решили, что нужен какой-то параметр self?

Comment: Код ошибки : TypeError: Wm.wm_withdraw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Нужен полный текст ошибки со стэктрейсом. Скорее всего проблема в `Toplevel.withdraw()` - нужно заменить на вызов метода `withdraw()` от объекта (конкретного окна), а не от класса.

Comment: если я пишу en.withdraw() (en это окно которое Toplevel(tk), то питон не находит переменную
en.withdraw()
NameError: name 'en' is not defined
если пишу Toplevel(tk), то нужен self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычные методы (не статические и не методы класса) должны вызываться от объектов (а не классов). При вызове метода от объекта в метод передается параметр `self`, содержащий ссылку на сам объект.

При вызове метода от класса параметр `self` не передается, из-за этого возникает ошибка `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` ("отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент 'self'").

Минимальный пример с такой проблемой:

```
class Test:
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello!")


test = Test()
test.hello()  # Выведет Hello!

Test.hello()  # Вылетит с ошибкой "TypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"
```

Чтобы исправить ошибку, нужно вызывать метод `withdraw()` от объекта окна, которое вы хотите скрыть, а не от класса `Toplevel`.

Чтобы получить доступ к переменной объекта предыдущего окна, нужно объявить ее глобальной в той функции, где она создается (в примере ниже в функции `window1`):

```
from tkinter import *


def window2():
    win1.withdraw()
    win2 = Toplevel()
    win2.geometry("400x200")
    win2.title("window2")
    Button(win2, text="Exit", command=lambda: root.destroy()).pack()



def window1():
    global win1  # Объявляем, что переменная win1 будет глобальной
    root.withdraw()
    win1 = Toplevel()
    win1.geometry("400x300")
    win1.title("window1")
    Button(win1, text="Next window", command=window2).pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")  
root.title("root")
Button(root, text="Next window", command=window1).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Другой вариант, можно передавать предыдущее окно через параметр:

```
from tkinter import *


def window2(prev_window):
    prev_window.withdraw()
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry("400x200")
    win.title("window2")
    Button(win, text="Show window1", command=lambda: window1(win)).pack()
    Button(win, text="Exit", command=lambda: root.destroy()).pack()



def window1(prev_window):
    prev_window.withdraw()
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry("400x300")
    win.title("window1")
    Button(win, text="Show window2", command=lambda: window2(win)).pack()
    Button(win, text="Exit", command=lambda: root.destroy()).pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")  
root.title("root")
Button(root, text="Show window1", command=lambda: window1(root)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cпасибо, очень помогло. Ответ засчитал.